Descriptions of Sea Dragon contain self-contradictory numbers. How can this be resolved?
The Sea Dragon was a breathtakingly audacious design concept from 1962. Its proposed mass was almost 4 times that of Starship. Hold onto your popcorn if you watch this: 

 . Sea Dragon foreshadowed many of starships advances such as low cost materials and full reusability.

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_Dragon_(rocket), the main engine was pressure-fed by liquid nitrogen (although other sources say pressure was supplied by methane) at 32atm for the RP-1 fuel and 17atm for the LOX. The rocket was to be made from 0.30” steel, and the rocket’s diameter was 78ft.
A pressure-fed rocket’s chamber pressure is limited by its tank pressure. In Sea Dragon’s case, chamber pressure would be limited by LOX to 17 atm (compared with the F-1’s 70 bar or Raptor’s 350 bar). Yet the Wikipedia article claims a chamber pressure of 20 atm
The effective exhaust velocity (and therefore the ISP) is proportional to the square root of the chamber pressure. So, all other things equal (they never are) Sea Dragon’s first stage would have an isp 1/2 that of the F-1, or 152 sec. Yet http://www.astronautix.com/s/seadragon-1.html gives ISP as 200 sec. And  https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19880069339/downloads/19880069339.pdf  gives an ISP of 242 sec
The hoop stress on a 70 ft diameter, 0.30” thick cylindrical tank pressurized to 32 bar would be 700,000 psi which is about 16x the tensile strength of steel.
The numbers seem all over the place. Is Sea Dragon just the stuff of legends? Is there an authoritative analysis of this concept? A report by Robert Traux in 1963 “A Feasibility Study of a Minimum Cost Heavy Launch Vehicle” is referred to as a primary source but Dr. Google is not familiar with it
EDIT Additional information is available from this surprisingly readable 1963 report by Aerojet-General under contract to NASA: https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19880069339/downloads/19880069339.pdf

I have, personally, only ever seen reference to the Sea Dragon in comparison infographics about different spacecraft. I've seen quite a few different designs for it, too. I haven't the authority to answer with certainly but that seems to suggest that it was either never seriously considered or was never really considered at all (maybe both).

This was a real feasibility effort.  I remember in early 60s talking with an associate at Edwards Rocket Propulsion Lab and discussing this with him.  He was part of a group doing this study.  We figured out some answers for him.  Idea was for the vehicle to be big, cheap, and use existing components where possible.  I had no other involvement other than an hour or so discussion.  I don't know where it ended up but I don't think anything was built.  It did stick in my mind for all these years though.

(Note that I VTC'd to get the "question is similar" comment, but without any particular malice.)

Where are you getting the 0.03"? Sea Dragon was going to be 0.3" (8mm) steel according to the Wikipedia article.

@RussellBorogove ... typo. You're right. Wikipedia says 0.30". Also, I found another reference to "aluminum tanks" so perhaps the steel skin was not part of the tank structure as it is in Starship.

"The effective exhaust velocity (and therefore the ISP) is proportional to the square root of the chamber pressure."
Source? If that were true you'd expect Raptor to have a specific impulse up in the 500s.

@RussellBorogove ...
"The effective exhaust velocity (and therefore the ISP) is proportional to the square root of the chamber pressure." Source? https://www.qrg.northwestern.edu/projects/vss/docs/Propulsion/3-how-you-calculate-specific-impulse.html

That's square root of chamber temp, not chamber pressure, if you're referencing the third approximation equation there.

I'm not seeing anything on the wiki page that mentions liquid nitrogen.

still needed to find out what feet and thumbs are used for in this particular context; hope there was more ideas like this sea dragon one
